# Is there a way to deploy only signed commits?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I have multiple repositories with multiple environments in each and I'm trying to find a way to use gitlab [sign commit mechanism](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/gpg_signed_commits/), to deploy only signed/verified commits to a specific environment and prevent unsigned/unverified commits from being deployed.

Comment: Maybe build on top of `git log --show-signature` once you are in your CI pipeline - but to my knowledge there is no native feature for that. See also this [related issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/208313)